# How to convert to String ArrayList with another specification, ArrayList<Person> in java

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Person> plot = new ArrayList<Person>();
        plot.add(new Person("John"));
        plot.add(new Person("Jane"));
        RepkaStory.tell(plot);
    }

    private static class Person implements RepkaStory {
       String name;
        private Person(String name) { this.name= name; }
    }

    public interface RepkaStory {
     static void tell(List<Person> a){
         for (Person x  :  a ) {
                System.out.println(x.toString); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it gives as result

```
 com.company.Main$Person@677327b6
    com.company.Main$Person@1540e19d
```

and I can't convert it into String.

Comment: Try to use `x.name` for printing

Comment: You have to override the `public String toString()` method which is inherited from  `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: `x.toString` should be `x.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

You should override toString method

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Person> plot = new ArrayList<Person>();
        plot.add(new Person("John"));
        plot.add(new Person("Jane"));
        RepkaStory.tell(plot);
    }

    private static class Person implements RepkaStory {
       String name;
        private Person(String name) { this.name= name; }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person [name=" + name + "]";
        }


    }

    public interface RepkaStory {
     static void tell(List<Person> a){
         for (Person x  :  a ) {
                System.out.println(x); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or use `System.out.println(x.name);`

Comment: Or use `System.out.println(x);`

Comment: @AxelH, yes it would work as well

Comment: It prevents a `NPE` if you have a `null` in the list.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the recommendation as this solution would be safe to use. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks all! I think I understand.